# Error trying to build aws-c-common package using CMake

Tags: c, amazon-web-services, clion

Hi I was trying to install and build the `aws-c-common` package provided by AWS.

However I encountered below errors when I'm trying to execute below command:

`cmake --build . && cmake --build . --target install && cd ..`

Which is the command that I'm following from [AWS Documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/encryption-sdk/latest/developer-guide/c-language-installation.html#c-language-how-to-install) Option B.

The error are shown as below (The error logs are very long and I can only pasted a portion of it here. But basically I can see error with each different file with different error reason, but I'm not sure why is it happening since I followed all the previous steps in the guide)

```
[1/58] Building C object CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/log_formatter.c.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/log_formatter.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DAWS_AFFINITY_METHOD=AWS_AFFINITY_METHOD_NONE -DAWS_COMMON_EXPORTS -DAWS_COMMON_USE_IMPORT_EXPORT -DHAVE_AVX2_INTRINSICS -DUSE_SIMD_ENCODING -DWINDOWS_KERNEL_LIB=Kernel32 -
Daws_c_common_EXPORTS -Ibuild/aws-c-common/include -Igenerated/include -O3 -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pedantic -Wno-long-long -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -std=gnu9
9 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/log_formatter.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\aws-c-common.dir\source\log_formatter.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/log_formatter.c.obj -c build/a
ws-c-common/source/log_formatter.c
In file included from build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/array_list.h:210:0,
                 from build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/byte_buf.h:8,
                 from build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/string.h:7,
                 from build/aws-c-common/source/log_formatter.c:9:
build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/array_list.inl: In function 'aws_array_list_debug_print':
build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/array_list.inl:99:48: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
         "arraylist %p. Alloc %p. current_size %zu. length %zu. item_size %zu. data %p\n",
                                                ^
build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/array_list.inl:99:60: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
         "arraylist %p. Alloc %p. current_size %zu. length %zu. item_size %zu. data %p\n",
                                                            ^
build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/array_list.inl:99:75: warning: unknown conversion type character 'z' in format [-Wformat=]
         "arraylist %p. Alloc %p. current_size %zu. length %zu. item_size %zu. data %p\n",
                                                                           ^
build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/array_list.inl:99:85: warning: format '%p' expects argument of type 'void *', but argument 4 has type 'size_t {aka const unsigned int}' [-Wformat=]
         "arraylist %p. Alloc %p. current_size %zu. length %zu. item_size %zu. data %p\n",
                                                                                     ^
build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/array_list.inl:99:9: warning: too many arguments for format [-Wformat-extra-args]
         "arraylist %p. Alloc %p. current_size %zu. length %zu. item_size %zu. data %p\n",
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/byte_order.h:69:0,
                 from build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/byte_buf.h:9,
                 from build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/string.h:7,
                 from build/aws-c-common/source/log_formatter.c:9:
build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/byte_order.inl: In function 'aws_hton64':
build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/byte_order.inl:47:23: warning: implicit declaration of function 'htonl' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     return ((uint64_t)htonl(low)) << 32 | htonl(high);
                       ^~~~~
build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/byte_order.inl: In function 'aws_hton32':
build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/byte_order.inl:63:38: warning: implicit declaration of function '_byteswap_ulong' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     return aws_is_big_endian() ? x : _byteswap_ulong(x);
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/byte_order.inl: In function 'aws_hton16':
build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/byte_order.inl:145:38: warning: implicit declaration of function '_byteswap_ushort' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     return aws_is_big_endian() ? x : _byteswap_ushort(x);
                                      ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/source/log_formatter.c: In function 'aws_format_standard_log_line':
build/aws-c-common/source/log_formatter.c:155:29: warning: implicit declaration of function 'vsnprintf_s' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
         int written_count = vsnprintf_s(
                             ^~~~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/source/log_formatter.c:158:13: error: '_TRUNCATE' undeclared (first use in this function)
             _TRUNCATE,
             ^~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/source/log_formatter.c:158:13: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
[2/58] Building C object CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/windows/rw_lock.c.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/windows/rw_lock.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DAWS_AFFINITY_METHOD=AWS_AFFINITY_METHOD_NONE -DAWS_COMMON_EXPORTS -DAWS_COMMON_USE_IMPORT_EXPORT -DHAVE_AVX2_INTRINSICS -DUSE_SIMD_ENCODING -DWINDOWS_KERNEL_LIB=Kernel32 -
Daws_c_common_EXPORTS -Ibuild/aws-c-common/include -Igenerated/include -O3 -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pedantic -Wno-long-long -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -std=gnu9
9 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/windows/rw_lock.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\aws-c-common.dir\source\windows\rw_lock.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/windows/rw_lock.c.obj -c b
uild/aws-c-common/source/windows/rw_lock.c
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/rw_lock.c:9:22: fatal error: synchapi.h: No such file or directory
 #include <synchapi.h>
                      ^
compilation terminated.
[3/58] Building C object CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/windows/clock.c.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/windows/clock.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DAWS_AFFINITY_METHOD=AWS_AFFINITY_METHOD_NONE -DAWS_COMMON_EXPORTS -DAWS_COMMON_USE_IMPORT_EXPORT -DHAVE_AVX2_INTRINSICS -DUSE_SIMD_ENCODING -DWINDOWS_KERNEL_LIB=Kernel32 -
Daws_c_common_EXPORTS -Ibuild/aws-c-common/include -Igenerated/include -O3 -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pedantic -Wno-long-long -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -std=gnu9
9 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/windows/clock.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\aws-c-common.dir\source\windows\clock.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/windows/clock.c.obj -c build/a
ws-c-common/source/windows/clock.c
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/clock.c:13:8: error: unknown type name 'INIT_ONCE'
 static INIT_ONCE s_timefunc_init_once = INIT_ONCE_STATIC_INIT;
        ^~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/clock.c:13:41: error: 'INIT_ONCE_STATIC_INIT' undeclared here (not in a function)
 static INIT_ONCE s_timefunc_init_once = INIT_ONCE_STATIC_INIT;
                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/clock.c:22:50: error: unknown type name 'PINIT_ONCE'
 static BOOL CALLBACK s_get_system_time_init_once(PINIT_ONCE init_once, PVOID param, PVOID *context) {
                                                  ^~~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/clock.c: In function 's_get_system_time_func_lazy_init':
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/clock.c:40:19: warning: implicit declaration of function 'InitOnceExecuteOnce' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     BOOL status = InitOnceExecuteOnce(&s_timefunc_init_once, s_get_system_time_init_once, NULL, NULL);
                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/clock.c:40:62: error: 's_get_system_time_init_once' undeclared (first use in this function)
     BOOL status = InitOnceExecuteOnce(&s_timefunc_init_once, s_get_system_time_init_once, NULL, NULL);
                                                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/clock.c:40:62: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
[4/58] Building C object CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/windows/condition_variable.c.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/windows/condition_variable.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DAWS_AFFINITY_METHOD=AWS_AFFINITY_METHOD_NONE -DAWS_COMMON_EXPORTS -DAWS_COMMON_USE_IMPORT_EXPORT -DHAVE_AVX2_INTRINSICS -DUSE_SIMD_ENCODING -DWINDOWS_KERNEL_LIB=Kernel32 -
Daws_c_common_EXPORTS -Ibuild/aws-c-common/include -Igenerated/include -O3 -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pedantic -Wno-long-long -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -std=gnu9
9 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/windows/condition_variable.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\aws-c-common.dir\source\windows\condition_variable.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/wind
ows/condition_variable.c.obj -c build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c
In file included from build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/allocator.h:8:0,
                 from build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/common.h:12,
                 from build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/condition_variable.h:9,
                 from build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:6:
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c: In function 'aws_condition_variable_init':
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:17:30: error: 'CONDITION_VARIABLE' undeclared (first use in this function)
     AWS_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(CONDITION_VARIABLE) == sizeof(condition_variable->condition_handle));
                              ^
build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/macros.h:18:40: note: in expansion of macro 'AWS_STATIC_ASSERT0'
 #define AWS_STATIC_ASSERT1(cond, line) AWS_STATIC_ASSERT0(cond, AWS_CONCAT(at_line_, line))
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/macros.h:19:33: note: in expansion of macro 'AWS_STATIC_ASSERT1'
 #define AWS_STATIC_ASSERT(cond) AWS_STATIC_ASSERT1(cond, __LINE__)
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:17:5: note: in expansion of macro 'AWS_STATIC_ASSERT'
     AWS_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(CONDITION_VARIABLE) == sizeof(condition_variable->condition_handle));
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:17:30: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
     AWS_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(CONDITION_VARIABLE) == sizeof(condition_variable->condition_handle));
                              ^
build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/macros.h:18:40: note: in expansion of macro 'AWS_STATIC_ASSERT0'
 #define AWS_STATIC_ASSERT1(cond, line) AWS_STATIC_ASSERT0(cond, AWS_CONCAT(at_line_, line))
                                        ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/macros.h:19:33: note: in expansion of macro 'AWS_STATIC_ASSERT1'
 #define AWS_STATIC_ASSERT(cond) AWS_STATIC_ASSERT1(cond, __LINE__)
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:17:5: note: in expansion of macro 'AWS_STATIC_ASSERT'
     AWS_STATIC_ASSERT(sizeof(CONDITION_VARIABLE) == sizeof(condition_variable->condition_handle));
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:20:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'InitializeConditionVariable' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     InitializeConditionVariable(AWSCV_TO_WINDOWS(condition_variable));
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:13:32: error: 'PCONDITION_VARIABLE' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define AWSCV_TO_WINDOWS(pCV) (PCONDITION_VARIABLE) & (pCV)->condition_handle
                                ^
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:20:33: note: in expansion of macro 'AWSCV_TO_WINDOWS'
     InitializeConditionVariable(AWSCV_TO_WINDOWS(condition_variable));
                                 ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c: In function 'aws_condition_variable_notify_one':
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:32:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'WakeConditionVariable' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     WakeConditionVariable(AWSCV_TO_WINDOWS(condition_variable));
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:13:32: error: 'PCONDITION_VARIABLE' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define AWSCV_TO_WINDOWS(pCV) (PCONDITION_VARIABLE) & (pCV)->condition_handle
                                ^
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:32:27: note: in expansion of macro 'AWSCV_TO_WINDOWS'
     WakeConditionVariable(AWSCV_TO_WINDOWS(condition_variable));
                           ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c: In function 'aws_condition_variable_notify_all':
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:38:5: warning: implicit declaration of function 'WakeAllConditionVariable' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     WakeAllConditionVariable(AWSCV_TO_WINDOWS(condition_variable));
     ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:13:32: error: 'PCONDITION_VARIABLE' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define AWSCV_TO_WINDOWS(pCV) (PCONDITION_VARIABLE) & (pCV)->condition_handle
                                ^
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:38:30: note: in expansion of macro 'AWSCV_TO_WINDOWS'
     WakeAllConditionVariable(AWSCV_TO_WINDOWS(condition_variable));
                              ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c: In function 'aws_condition_variable_wait':
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:46:9: warning: implicit declaration of function 'SleepConditionVariableSRW' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     if (SleepConditionVariableSRW(AWSCV_TO_WINDOWS(condition_variable), AWSMUTEX_TO_WINDOWS(mutex), INFINITE, 0)) {
         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:13:32: error: 'PCONDITION_VARIABLE' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define AWSCV_TO_WINDOWS(pCV) (PCONDITION_VARIABLE) & (pCV)->condition_handle
                                ^
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:46:35: note: in expansion of macro 'AWSCV_TO_WINDOWS'
     if (SleepConditionVariableSRW(AWSCV_TO_WINDOWS(condition_variable), AWSMUTEX_TO_WINDOWS(mutex), INFINITE, 0)) {
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:9:0:
build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/mutex.h:12:42: error: 'PSRWLOCK' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #    define AWSMUTEX_TO_WINDOWS(pMutex) (PSRWLOCK) & (pMutex)->mutex_handle
                                          ^
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:46:73: note: in expansion of macro 'AWSMUTEX_TO_WINDOWS'
     if (SleepConditionVariableSRW(AWSCV_TO_WINDOWS(condition_variable), AWSMUTEX_TO_WINDOWS(mutex), INFINITE, 0)) {
                                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c: In function 'aws_condition_variable_wait_for':
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:13:32: error: 'PCONDITION_VARIABLE' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #define AWSCV_TO_WINDOWS(pCV) (PCONDITION_VARIABLE) & (pCV)->condition_handle
                                ^
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:63:35: note: in expansion of macro 'AWSCV_TO_WINDOWS'
     if (SleepConditionVariableSRW(AWSCV_TO_WINDOWS(condition_variable), AWSMUTEX_TO_WINDOWS(mutex), time_ms, 0)) {
                                   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:9:0:
build/aws-c-common/include/aws/common/mutex.h:12:42: error: 'PSRWLOCK' undeclared (first use in this function)
 #    define AWSMUTEX_TO_WINDOWS(pMutex) (PSRWLOCK) & (pMutex)->mutex_handle
                                          ^
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/condition_variable.c:63:73: note: in expansion of macro 'AWSMUTEX_TO_WINDOWS'
     if (SleepConditionVariableSRW(AWSCV_TO_WINDOWS(condition_variable), AWSMUTEX_TO_WINDOWS(mutex), time_ms, 0)) {
                                                                         ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
[5/58] Building C object CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/windows/file.c.obj
FAILED: CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/windows/file.c.obj
C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe -DAWS_AFFINITY_METHOD=AWS_AFFINITY_METHOD_NONE -DAWS_COMMON_EXPORTS -DAWS_COMMON_USE_IMPORT_EXPORT -DHAVE_AVX2_INTRINSICS -DUSE_SIMD_ENCODING -DWINDOWS_KERNEL_LIB=Kernel32 -
Daws_c_common_EXPORTS -Ibuild/aws-c-common/include -Igenerated/include -O3 -DNDEBUG -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes -fno-omit-frame-pointer -pedantic -Wno-long-long -fPIC -fvisibility=hidden -std=gnu9
9 -MD -MT CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/windows/file.c.obj -MF CMakeFiles\aws-c-common.dir\source\windows\file.c.obj.d -o CMakeFiles/aws-c-common.dir/source/windows/file.c.obj -c build/aws-
c-common/source/windows/file.c
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/file.c: In function 'aws_fopen':
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/file.c:18:17: error: 'EINVAL' undeclared (first use in this function)
         errno = EINVAL;
                 ^~~~~~
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/file.c:18:17: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
build/aws-c-common/source/windows/file.c:27:9: warning: implicit declaration of function '_wfopen_s' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]
     if (_wfopen_s(&file, w_file_path, w_mode)) {
         ^~~~~~~~~
```

Does anyone know how to resolve this?
Thank you.

Comment: Do you know if your MinGW is 32 bit or 64 bit ? It might need 64bit MinGW. I'd try building following the directions under the Windows tab of the aws page you linked to build with Visual Studio. Or build it in the [WSL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Subsystem_for_Linux) environment.

Comment: @lgflorentino My MinGW is 32, I installed from Official GUI Install Manager, I will try with 64 one, thank you!

Comment: @lgflorentino Unfortunately same happened after I installed MinGW64 and removed 32...